# Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ ~ After Installing Python 3 OS X

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Everything was going smoothly until I needed to install Pillow. I did my regular command of `pip3 install pillow` and it downloaded perfectly. The only issue was It automatically installed the latest version which isn't compatible with python 2.7. Plus the PIL wasn't working properly. So I thought I'd download python 3 from the main website fully up to date. After doing this the `pip3 install` command no longer works and gives me an error.

I assume the upgrade screwed something over and I have no idea how to properly remove it if so. I've been browsing along reading other people with the issue and have tried everything I could. Some people are way too technical and I have no idea what they are saying or telling what to do. I'm a newer mac user switching from a windows machine.

OS X Version: 10.10.5

Python: 2.7.10

Log;

`MacBook-Pro:src George$ pip3 install pillow
Downloading/unpacking pillow
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pillow
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/George/.pip/pip.log`

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip3 run on Wed May 27 15:39:27 2020
Downloading/unpacking pillow
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/: connection error: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:598)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/ when looking for download links for pillow
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/ (Caused by <class 'http.client.CannotSendRequest'>: Request-sent)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for pillow
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for pillow:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/: connection error: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:598)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pillow/ when looking for download links for pillow
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pillow
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /private/var/folders/vz/2_2d8xqj2hqbwwbmdqscvt_80000gn/T/pip_build_George...
No distributions at all found for pillow
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `pip install pillow` to install this package in python2.

Answer (score 0):

`pip3` is intended for use with `python 3`. Try `pip` instead. You also will likely want to use `pyenv`, and `conda/miniconda` so that you are not using your system python for all endeavors, as many packages can cause incompatibilities. Happy coding!